# $ \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{ka+n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

As part of self study towards entrance exams I am solving the following question.

$$ \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{ka+n} $$

A. $0$

B. $ln(a)$

C. $\frac{1}{a} ln(1+a)$

D. None of the above

On the onset, it looked like a sum of an infinite HP. I looked up online for the relevant material but it was far too complex for the level of problems that I am dealing with right now and certainly feels like I am missing something here. Please drop a hint as to how to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

The sum $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{1+a(k/n)}$ is a Riemann sum.  Can you finish now?

Comment: Yes! Got it! $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+ax} dx$. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.